# Searching for a jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

i hope you can help me. 
I'm looking for a "special" Datepicker JS/jQuery which needs some special Options:

I'll try to explain you with the help of the jQuery UI Datepicker
- the same function as the Inline Datepicker
- 2 Datepickers has to be shown at the same time
- it should be possible to disable Dates !!!!!!!!!!! (thats the Problem why i do not use the jQuery UI Datepicker !)

Can someone give me a good hint?

Thx and have a nice weekend.
Sascha

Comment: What do you meant by "it should be possible to disable Dates"?

Answer (score 3):

See this:

**[JQuery DatePicker](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/)**

Answer (score 1):

Okay Guys,

found the Solution for the jQuery UI Datepicker myself.
To all of you "Thank you".

If someone is also interested:

http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days